# Function invocation shorthand in Lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of functions that I'd like to execute using Lodash. Contrived example:

```
const functions = [
    () => console.log('Fn 1'),
    () => console.log('Fn 2')
];

_(functions).each(fn => fn());
```

Is there a Lodash builtin that performs the equivalent of `fn => fn()` in my code above? I think `_(functions).each(_.invoke)` or similar would express the intent of the code more clearly.

Comment: It looks like you're already using the best shorthand.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect I am. I haven't been able to find anything more readable. I don't have any real problem with it, but `fn => fn()` looks odd the first time I look at it. It's a very minor nitpick :)

Comment: There are no ways with Lodash that I'm aware of.

Comment: Why are you focused on using lodash?

Comment: `()` **IS** the function invocation "shorthand".

Comment: @tozaburo because this is something I encountered that I'm interested in learning about. My project already makes extensive use of Lodash so there's no reason not to use it here.

I'm aware that what I'm doing is already a shorthand; I'm simply interested in learning about alternate approaches, like what Luis has provided in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code isn't wrong, if you still want the lodash solution there's `invokeMap`. `invokeMap` will invoke a function (not your array of functions) after each iteration. Also, you can pass arguments to the function that's being invoked.

```
const functions = [
    () => console.log('Fn 1'),
    () => console.log('Fn 2')
];

_.invokeMap(functions, Function.prototype.call);
```

Comment: Nice, this is an interesting approach. This is longer than mind, but also arguably more readable, though it requires a bit more understanding.

I think I'll keep my solution, but this is essentially what I was looking for, thanks!